# Dictionary with Tuple as Key GetHashCode is not called

Tags: c#, dictionary, .net-core, hashtable

**Description**

---

Trying to create a Dictionary with Tuple as the key.

However the GetHashCode and Equals functions are not being called, hence duplicate keys will be added to the dictionary.

This is the `Key`class that I want to use as my Dictionary's key:

```
class Key : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<int, int>>
    {
        private Tuple<int, int> _tuple;

        public Key(int a, int b)
        {
            _tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(a, b);
        }


        public bool Equals(Tuple<int, int> x, Tuple<int, int> y)
        {
            return (x.Item1 == y.Item1 && x.Item2 == y.Item2);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Tuple<int, int> obj)
        {
            return obj.Item1.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Item2.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Driver code:

```
public static void Main() {

    var map = new Dictionary<Key, int>();

    map.Add(new Key(1, 2), 3);
    map.Add(new Key(1, 2), 4); // <==== Should not add!
}
```

**Questions**

---

How to fix this?

What is the easiest implementation for `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>` to work properly?

Comment: Your question doesn't include a good [mcve], so it's not possible to understand your scenario. But if you intend for the `Key` class to be used as the comparer for the dictionary, you need to pass an instance of that to the constructor when you create the dictionary. Fix your question.

Comment: are you passing the equality comparer as a contructor parameter of the dictionaty? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__

Comment: And if you *do* intend for the `Key` class to be used as the comparer, there's no reason that the constructor should be taking a tuple instance. It looks like you're dealing with a mix of concerns.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Updated with the code to see how I'm using it.

Comment: Re your edit: your dictionary key is the `Key` class but it doesn't implement `IEquatable<Key>`. You implemented the wrong interface for what you want to happen.

Comment: @madreflection Even when I change `IEqualityComparer` to `IEquatable<Key>` and implement it, still same issue. I'll get values with duplicate keys in my `map`.

Comment: Show *that* implementation. If it didn't work you need to fix *that*. `IEqualityComparer<T>` is an XY problem.

Comment: Even better, use `Tuple<int,int>` or `(int,int)` (that is, `ValueTuple<int,int>`) as your key. They have all the equality functionality you need.

Comment: Because `Equals` should compare instances of `Key` not `Tuple<int, int>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use own class `Key`:

```
    public class Key
    {
        public Key(int item1, int item2)
        {
            Tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(item1, item2);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (obj is Key other)
            {
                return Tuple.Equals(other.Tuple);
            }

            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Tuple.GetHashCode();
        }

        public Tuple<int, int> Tuple { get; private set; }
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        var map = new Dictionary<Key, int>();
        map.Add(new Key(1, 2), 3);
        map.Add(new Key(1, 2), 4); // will throw System.ArgumentException
    }
```

Another way is just using `Tuple` class:

```
    public void Do()
    {
        var map = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>();
        map.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2), 3);
        map.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2), 4); // will throw System.ArgumentException
    }
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. You can use `return _tuple.Item1 == other._tuple.Item1 && _tuple.Item2 == other._tuple.Item2;` in the Equals method and get rid of the `public int Item1 => _tuple.Item1;` (eventhough `_tuple` is private, it works.)

Comment: In first approach you can just compare two tuple instances because tuple compared by values by default and for same reason second approach is redundant,.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to use `ValueTuple` as a key, which will be compared by it's values by default.

```
public static void Main() 
{
    var map = new Dictionary<(int, int), int>();

    map.Add((1, 2), 3);
    map.Add((1, 2), 4); // Throw an exception
}
```

If you like to have own class to represent a key you can simply create subclass of `Tuple<int, int>` and get required behaviour "for free"

```
public class Key : Tuple<int, int>
{
    public Key(int item1, int item2) : base(item1, item2)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! Worth mentioning that this requires installing `System.ValueTuple` package.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, when adding an item to the dictionary, the default `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods are being called, which use a reference comparison to determine equality.

If you want to override this behavior, then you need to use the `override` keyword, and override the method:

```
class Key : IEquatable<Key>
{
    private readonly Tuple<int, int> tuple;

    public Key(int a, int b)
    {
        tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(a, b);
    }

    public bool Equals(Key other)
    {
        return other != null && 
            tuple.Item1 == other.tuple.Item1 && 
            tuple.Item2 == other.tuple.Item2;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Key);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return tuple.Item1.GetHashCode() ^ tuple.Item2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Voted up, but I think @Dmitry's answer is simpler; it does not even implement `IEquatable` just overrides, GetHashCode and Equals.

Comment: @A-Sharabiani Thx. I feel like it's cleaner to have the separate `Equals` method that takes in a `Key` (it avoids the checking and casting when a `Key` is passed), but it could easily all go in one method.

Answer (score 1):

You could try following solution.

```
public class Key : IEquatable<Key>
{
    private Tuple<int, int> _tuple;

    public Key(int a, int b)
    {
        _tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(a, b);
    }

    public bool Equals(Key other)
    {
        return (this.GetHashCode() == other.GetHashCode());
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _tuple.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Just posting a simplified version of @Dmitri's answer as a reference here.*

The simplest way (without installing extra packages) and not implementing any interfaces, is to just override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods as follows:

```
public class Key
{
    private readonly Tuple<int, int> _tuple;

    public Key(int item1, int item2)
    {
        _tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(item1, item2);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Key;
        return _tuple.Item1 == other?._tuple.Item1 && _tuple.Item2 == other?._tuple.Item2;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _tuple.Item1.GetHashCode() ^ _tuple.Item2.GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

Comment: @RufusL Why would `obj` be `null` or not a `Key`?

Comment: @RufusL updated the answer by adding Safe Navigation operator. Also tested with `null` and objects of types other than `Key`.

Comment: `Equals` can be rewritten to simple `return _tuple.Equals(obj)`

Comment: `GetHashCode` can be rewritten to simple `return _tuple.GetHashCode()`

Comment: Looks like deriving from `Tuple<int, int>` will get behaviour you want "for free" ;)